# Making sure a query gets executed

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a server which executes properly 9/10 times, but sometimes I get the error *“Lost connection to MySQL server during query”* and then the whole process stops/freezes.

I'm trying to let a MySQL query execute again if it fails using a function for this, unfortunately it seems that the code 'stops' or get stuck whenever I get an error. Am I doing something wrong?

Here string is something like: `SELECT xx FROM xxx WHERE xxx`

```
try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect (host = "",
         user = "",
         passwd = "",
         db = "" )
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print("Error %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
    sys.exit(1);
cursor = db.cursor()

def mysql_handling(string):
    while 1:
        try:
            cursor.execute(string)
            if 'SELECT' not in string:
                db.commit()           
            break
        except:
            mysql_error_tracking(string)
```

`mysql_error_tracking` is a function to monitor what queries fail most of the time (not relevant).

Comment: Could be any of these: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: I've been through this already, I just want to detect when it goes wrong and try again.

Comment: Also, just put `mysql_error_tracking` function in the `except` block; no need to create an extra identifier, `x`, just for it.

Comment: So, by *been though this*, you mean you also tried adding a timeout?

Comment: Only enhancing the memory by adjusting max_allowed_packet to 64M (because I got multiple connections at the same time). I'll try to add the timeout and I'll let you know if it works

Comment: @Tshepang what in the configuration file my.cnf should I change to add the timeout? or is there any file that enables me to use the new timeout setting even after restarting the server?

Comment: Specify it in your `connect` function: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes in your code.

Comment: Default timeout seems to be infinite, is it better to adjust it then?

Comment: For sure. That's likely why your script gets stuck.

Comment: Does this mean I have to reset the database connection everytime a timeout occurs, or is this timeout only for the queries executed?

Comment: The only change needed is in your script.

Comment: `            db = MySQLdb.connect (host = "",
                user = "",
                passwd = "",
                db = "",
                connect_timeout = "10" )`

something like this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25419/discussion-between-tshepang-and-lazykiddy)

Answer (score 0):

Add a timeout to your connection method:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect (host = HOST, user = USER, passwd = PASS, db = DB,
                      connect_timeout = TIMEOUT)
```

Do this in your `except` block so that you do a re-connect.

To make your life easier, place your connection code in a separate function so you can re-use it. Something like this (untested):

```
def get_cursor()
    try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect (host = HOST, user = USER, passwd = PASS, db = DB,
                          connect_timeout = TIMEOUT)
    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        print("Error %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        sys.exit(1);
    return db.cursor()

def mysql_handling(cursor, string):
    while True:
        try:
            cursor.execute(string)
            if 'SELECT' not in string:
                db.commit()    
            break
        except MySQLdb.MySQLError:
            cursor.close()
            mysql_error_tracking(string)
            cursor = get_cursor()

def main():
    mysql_handling(get_cursor(), string)
```

Comment: Thank you! Only won't this code return in an infinite loop if the query is not correct?